# Настройка беспроводного интернета

Tags: windows, сеть, администрирование, windows-10

К моему компьютеру подключен проводной интернет. Иногда бывает, что он пропадает. Страшно, когда я провожу стрим или играю в онлайн игру и интернет неожиданно вырубается на 5 минут. Когда это происходит, я подключаю свой телефон к компу и врубаю режим USB модема, и кушаю мобильный интернет. Проблема в том, что мне надо постоянно его (мобильный инт) включать, когда основной интернет вырубается, и сам по себе интернет мобильный не бесконечный, поэтому мне ещё надо его периодически выключать. Возник такой вопрос. Возможно ли настроить мои подключения так, чтобы компьютер менял сеть на мобильную, если основная падает, и наоборот, сразу же переключаться на основную сеть, когда та заработает.

Система Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: судя по тому, что существуют платные решения этой задачи, это сделать не очень просто

Comment: Кто мешает поменять провайдера?